# Vim: Command-line selection

Tags: vim, command-line, range

Instead of using a range to focus an action, say:

```
5,10/booboo  <-- to find "booboo" between lines 5 and 10
```

or

```
5,10g/booboo/d  <-- to delete "booboo" between lines 5 and 10
```

I was wondering if I can search for the range ***within the command-line***.  (I understand the visual selection and act within that range.)  All I can think of is to search for the first instance of a phrase and mark it:

```
:g/blahblah/mark a
```

Then the second instance:

```
:g/bleepbleep/mark b
```

Then perform what I want within that region:

```
:'a,'bg/booboo/d
```

I'm thinking there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
:/blahblah/,/bleepbleep/g/booboo/d
```

You can even get a little bit more fancy and send the cursor to the top of the document first:

```
:0;/blahblah/,/bleepbleep/g/booboo/d
```

See also `:help [range]`